# Why do Computer Navigation Fixes still exist now that GPS waypoints can be used to define tracks?

Tags: gnss

A CNF is a point that defines a navigation track for a GPS, but why is it used when you there are GPS waypoints that are created to define a track?

Answer (score 5):

From the AIM 1−1−17. Global Positioning System (GPS)

> (2) A Computer Navigation Fix (CNF) is also a point defined by a
>   latitude/longitude coordinate and is required to support
>   Performance−Based Navigation (PBN) operations. The GPS receiver uses
>   CNFs in conjunction with waypoints to navigate from point to point.
>   However, CNFs are not recognized by ATC. … CNFs that do appear on
>   aeronautical charts allow pilots increased situational awareness by
>   identifying points in the aircraft database route of flight with
>   points on the aeronautical chart. CNFs are random five-letter
>   identifiers, not pronounceable like waypoints and placed in
>   parenthesis. Eventually, all CNFs will begin with the letters “CF”
>   followed by three consonants (for example, CFWBG).

As an example, the glide slope intercept for an ILS that I fly shows up in the Garmin 430 as a waypoint since the GPS requires a FAF to sequence to the MAP in order to conduct an approach. But it does not show up on the chart. (Remember that an ILS doesn’t have a FAF on the chart.) I have seen them on charts, but none come to mind right now.

Comment: Interesting thing about these "unpronouceable" fixes is that many of them ARE pronounceable, such as "AFWOX", northwest of BFF on V247.